# CSS/HTML Twitter bootstrap fixed columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get some elements on my webpage to stay where they are when scrolling (fixed), but I can't seem to get it working using `position:fixed;`.

When I try the design gets pretty broken. Everything moves to the right side, and is getting 100% in width automatically. All elements I want to set fixed also stays on top of each other...[image: see image]

This is how it is supposed to look...
[image]

The header (blue bar) and the row below is going to stay fixed where it is. How would I do that using Twitters Bootstrap?

Here is some HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div id="search_wrapper" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 grey">

        <div id="search" class="col-md-12">

            <div class="threed left"></div>
            <div class="threed right"></div>

            <a href="/"><div class="logo_small"></div></a>
            <form method="post" class="search">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="form-control-feedback pull-right" type="submit" name="submit_search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Søk etter firma, bransje og sted">
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <div id="locals_wrapper" class="col-md-3 grey">

            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Steder</h3>
            <hr>

            <?php

                if (isset($data['location']) && $data['location']) {

                    foreach ($data['location'] as $c => $ms) {

                        echo '<div class="county checkbox"><label> <input class="c" type="checkbox" name="business_county" value="'. $c .'">'. $c .' </label><div class="municipalities" data-county="'. $c .'">';
                        foreach ($ms as $m) {
                            echo '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="business_municipality" data-county="'. $c .'" value="'. $m .'">'. $m .'</label></div>';
                        } echo '</div></div>';

                    }

                }

            ?>

        </div>

        <div id="results_wrapper" class="col-md-9 grey">

            <h3><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>Resultater</i></h3>
            <hr>

            <div id="results">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

I have tried adding `position:fixed;` to `#search, #wrapper`.

Comment: Please post some HTML and CSS that you've tried

Comment: Did you watch the html compiled ?

Comment: ... html after php has been compiled...

Comment: Can you post the output of the PHP? You're not having problems with that so it doesn't make sense to include it. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can create a quick jsfiddle to show you the problem. Give me a minute

Comment: This is how it looks without being fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/uhefa1b5/2/
This is happening when i try to fix the elements I want to be fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/uhefa1b5/3/